# Get schema name from a properties file

Tags: spring, ibatis, mybatis

I'm having an issue at the moment that I've been doing alot of searching on but still havent found an answer.

**Backgorund of problem:** We have multiple DB schemas at the one URL including test copies of schemas (e.g schema1, schema2, schema1_test, schema2_test are all at the same url). I'm trying to make which version of each schema is used configurable via a properties file.

We are using Spring and mybatis, and unfortunately i'm new to both (so please excuse my ignorance or any mistakes i make describing the issue!)

So in my spring config file, which is stored under /src/main/resources, I have the following snippets:
(I only added "configLocation" property and later added "sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" property)

```
<!-- define the SqlSessionFactory -->
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.example.domain" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatisConfig.xml" />
</bean>

<!-- scan for mappers and let them be autowired -->
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.example.something.persistence" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

My mybatisConfig.xml (which is stored under /src/main/resources, which should be on the class path)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN" 
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
<properties resource="sqlmapconfig.properties" />
</configuration>
```

sqlmapconfig.properties (in same folder)

```
schema1=schema1_test
```

And I try reference the property in one of the mapper files in com.example.something.persistence:

```
 <select id="test" resultType="result" parameterType="long">
    select ${schema1}.table.col  
    from ${schema1}.table 
 </select>
```

When I try build with maven it fails a test:

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'schema1' in 'class java.lang.Long'
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "stored under /src/main/resources, which should be on the class path" <== Can you confirm this to be the case? Do you have the folder  "/src/main/resources" on the classpath, or is your build copying it somewhere?

Comment: Yeah it is on the classpath. It is a webapp that will get deployed to a tomcat server.

[EDIT - submitted by mistake]
Even if i take out the classpath part and leave it as a relative url link (they are in the same folder) it doesn't change anything.

Is there any intermediate step where I can read the {$schema1} to narrow down where the issue is?

Comment: It occurs to me that you're specifying the properties file for the config, but using the property references in your mapper file. As far as I know, the properties are not carried over to the mappers file.

What database are you using? Can you specify the schema in your JDBC URL?

Comment: Thanks for the replies:
Its a Sybase db that I (or anyone else on my team) can make no changes to.

I cant specify it in the URL as there is more than one schema on that url (Some queries even join from more than one schema e.g. schema1 & schema2)

EDIT: I maybe confusing schemas with catalogs, but its still the same problem im trying to achieve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I gave up on trying to read the properties directly and went down the passing it in from Java route

So I had to change the "parameterType" to be a map in the mapper file

```
<select id="test" resultType="result" parameterType="map">
    select ${schema1}.table.col  
    from ${schema1}.table where number=#{number}
</select>
```

And edited the java mapper code as follows

```
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;

...

public List<result> test(@Param("number") long number, @Param("schema1") String schema1);
```

Hope this helps someone.

**Notes & References:**

Careful on the use of ${} vs #{}, differences explained [here](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-mybatis)

How to use multiple params wwas taking from [here](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/HowToSelectMultipleParams)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and managed to do this by creating custom `LanguageDriver`. Language drivers in mybatis have few hook methods. The interesting one is `createSqlSource` which is called while loading every defined sql statement. This allows you to modify the statement at this point. The best way to do this is to extend the `XMLLanguageDriver` which is the default driver which interprets the queries defined in xml files and in annotations.

The first thing to do is to modify your queries by adding some marker which will be replaced with schema (SCHEMA_MARKER is imported from custom laguage driver class which is presented below):

```
public interface MyMabatisMapper {
  @Select("select * from " + SCHEMA_MARKER + ".myTable ")
  List<MyObjects> getObjects();
}
```

Now we create custom language driver which will replace the marker with given schema.

Example:

```
public class QueriesModifyingDriver extends XMLLanguageDriver {

  public static final String SCHEMA_MARKER = "###MY_SCHEMA###";
  public static final String SCHEMA_MARKER_PATTERN = SCHEMA.replaceAll("#", "\\#");

  private final String schemaName;

  // NOTE: Name of the schema passed in constructor !!!
  public QueriesModifyingDriver(String schemaName) {
    this.schemaName = schemaName;
  }

  @Override
  public SqlSource createSqlSource(org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration configuration, String script, Class<?> parameterType) { 
    String modifiedScript = script.replaceAll(SCHEMA_MARKER_PATTERN, schemaName);

    return super.createSqlSource(configuration, modifiedScript, parameterType);
  }
};
```

Above we passed the name of our schema via constructor to our language driver. Now all we need to do is to install this language driver to mybatis. Example below assumes that Spring is used using annotations configuration. Schema name is read from property my.schema.name, but it can be obtained from any source of course:

```
  @Bean
  public SqlSessionFactory mybatisSqlSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource, @Value("${my.schema.name}") String schemaName) throws Exception {

    SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);

    org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration mybatisConfiguration = sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject().getConfiguration();

    QueriesModifyingDriver queriesModifyingDriver = new QueriesModifyingDriver(schemaName);
    mybatisConfiguration.getLanguageRegistry().register(queriesModifyingDriver);

    mybatisConfiguration.setDefaultScriptingLanguage(QueriesModifyingDriver.class);

    return sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
  }
```

Please note that this is quite effective way because language driver processes every queryonly once (on startup) and this modified queries are later reused by mybatis.

Comment: this only happen on boot time right? is it possible to modify the script on each request? i want to set the schema per request

Comment: @aldo This is only once. If you need to do per each request you probably need to write your own mybatus query interceptor